# React Native - React Packager sends old code

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to use React Native for Android Development under Windows 10, so I'm using Genymotion to emulate an Android device.

I start react by callin `react-native run-android` in the directory which contains the index.android.js file. Everything runs succesfully and on my virtual device the app opens with Welcome to React text.

The problem is when I try to change the index.android.js. I save the changes and the app remains the same ( I have hot reloading and Live reloading enabled). Even when I double press R, the app doesn't show new text. I need to close the react packager and run it again for the app to show changes.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run this line bellow:

```
watchman watch-del-all
```

or:

```
rm -fr /usr/local/var/run/watchman/$USER-state
```